# highcharts svg element with inline style tooltip

Tags: javascript, svg, highcharts

I want to add a tooltip to an SVG element that I created with the renderer function. The tooltip text should be partially bold. Unfortunately the following code does not work - the word is not written bold.

```
var circle = renderer.circle(100, 100, 50)
  .attr({
    fill: 'red',
    stroke: 'black',
    'stroke-width': 2,
    title: 'This is the partially <b>bold</b> Tooltip for the circle'
  })
  .add();
```

JsFiddle:
https://jsfiddle.net/martindfurrer/bm1djhpw/10/

Comment: You won't be able to style the <title> tag. Instead use try using the highcharts tooltip: https://www.highcharts.com/docs/chart-concepts/tooltip

Comment: Can you give me an example?

Answer (score 1):

The circle title is not specifically the Highcharts thing, but just svg tag, and I'm not sure if it possible to bold it
https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/SVG/Element/title ;

When it comes to the second approach - the `circle` you've created using the renderer does not have a built-in tooltip property like data points in a series. You will need to create a custom tooltip:

```
events: {
  load: function () {
    const renderer = this.renderer;
    const series = this.series[0];

    series.circle = renderer.circle(100, 100, 50)
      .attr({
        fill: 'red',
        stroke: 'black',
        'stroke-width': 2,
      })
      .add();

    series.circle.on('mouseover', function () {
      if (!series.customTooltip) {
        series.customTooltip = renderer.label(
          'This is the partially <b>bold</b> tooltip for the circle',
          series.circle.x,
          series.circle.y
        ).add();
      }
      series.customTooltip.show();
    });

    series.circle.on('mouseout', function () {
      if (series.customTooltip) {
        series.customTooltip.destroy();
        series.customTooltip = null;
      }
    });
  }
}
```

Demo:
https://jsfiddle.net/BlackLabel/hd01y3j7/

I'm not sure about your specific requirements, but you can also consider using a point to achieve a similar outcome:

Demo:
https://jsfiddle.net/BlackLabel/7kma8tsb/